# Supply an equivalence relation on R whose equivalence classes are $\{[m,m+1)|m\in Z\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Supply an equivalence relation on R whose equivalence classes are $\{[m,m+1)|m\in Z\}$

Define $\sim :R\to R$ as

$\forall x,y\in R \\ x \sim y \iff \exists m\in Z \ni x,y \in [m,m+1)$

Will this suffice?

Comment: Yes... you need to fix the formula $\exists{m\in Z}, x,y\in[m,m+1)$.

Comment: They probably wanted you to write something like this $x\sim y \iff \lfloor x\rfloor = \lfloor y\rfloor$ though

Comment: @Yanko No need to fix anything. The symbol $\ni$ is used here for "such that". This is a rather rare use of this symbol, but it's common among some authors.

Comment: @MarsPlastic Oh really? first time I see such a thing. Good to know!

Comment: @Yanko Yes, I've only learned this relatively recently myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly we have no problem with reflection and simmetry.

Transitivity:

$x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$ then $x,y\in [m,m+1)$ (and thus $[y]=m$) and $y,z\in [n,n+1)$  (and thus $[y]=n$)   so $m=n$ and thus $x,z\in [m,m+1)$ so $x\sim z$.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition is good, but it’s tautological.

Hint: this is linked to the greatest integer function. 
Define $\lfloor x\rfloor$ to be the largest integer less than or equal to $x$.

Next, $x\sim y$ is $\lfloor x\rfloor= \lfloor y\rfloor$.

Comment: It is worth to note that one has an equivalence relation if $x\sim y \iff f(x)=f(y)$ for a certain function $f$, here "integer part".